# PHPExcel Pie graph error

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm trying to make a pie chart in PHP Excel, but I'm not getting it to work. I've made a working Bar graph, and that works flawlessly. But this example of PHPExcel doesn't work:

```
<?php



/** PHPExcel */
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../Classes/PHPExcel.php';


$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
$objWorksheet->fromArray(
    array(
        array('',   2010,   2011,   2012),
        array('Q1',   12,   15,     21),
        array('Q2',   56,   73,     86),
        array('Q3',   52,   61,     69),
        array('Q4',   30,   32,     0),
    )
);


//  Set the Labels for each data series we want to plot
//      Datatype
//      Cell reference for data
//      Format Code
//      Number of datapoints in series
//      Data values
//      Data Marker
$dataseriesLabels1 = array(
    new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Worksheet!$C$1', NULL, 1),   //  2011
);
//  Set the X-Axis Labels
//      Datatype
//      Cell reference for data
//      Format Code
//      Number of datapoints in series
//      Data values
//      Data Marker
$xAxisTickValues1 = array(
    new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Worksheet!$A$2:$A$5', NULL, 4),  //  Q1 to Q4
);
//  Set the Data values for each data series we want to plot
//      Datatype
//      Cell reference for data
//      Format Code
//      Number of datapoints in series
//      Data values
//      Data Marker
$dataSeriesValues1 = array(
    new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('Number', 'Worksheet!$C$2:$C$5', NULL, 4),
);

//  Build the dataseries
$series1 = new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries(
    PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::TYPE_PIECHART,               // plotType
    PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::GROUPING_STANDARD,           // plotGrouping
    range(0, count($dataSeriesValues1)-1),                  // plotOrder
    $dataseriesLabels1,                                     // plotLabel
    $xAxisTickValues1,                                      // plotCategory
    $dataSeriesValues1                                      // plotValues
);

//  Set up a layout object for the Pie chart
$layout1 = new PHPExcel_Chart_Layout();
$layout1->setShowVal(TRUE);
$layout1->setShowPercent(TRUE);

//  Set the series in the plot area
$plotarea1 = new PHPExcel_Chart_PlotArea($layout1, array($series1));
//  Set the chart legend
$legend1 = new PHPExcel_Chart_Legend(PHPExcel_Chart_Legend::POSITION_RIGHT, NULL, false);

$title1 = new PHPExcel_Chart_Title('Test Pie Chart');


//  Create the chart
$chart1 = new PHPExcel_Chart(
    'chart1',       // name
    $title1,        // title
    $legend1,       // legend
    $plotarea1,     // plotArea
    true,           // plotVisibleOnly
    0,              // displayBlanksAs
    NULL,           // xAxisLabel
    NULL            // yAxisLabel       - Pie charts don't have a Y-Axis
);

//  Set the position where the chart should appear in the worksheet
$chart1->setTopLeftPosition('A7');
$chart1->setBottomRightPosition('H20');

//  Add the chart to the worksheet
$objWorksheet->addChart($chart1);


//  Set the Labels for each data series we want to plot
//      Datatype
//      Cell reference for data
//      Format Code
//      Number of datapoints in series
//      Data values
//      Data Marker
$dataseriesLabels2 = array(
    new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Worksheet!$C$1', NULL, 1),   //  2011
);
//  Set the X-Axis Labels
//      Datatype
//      Cell reference for data
//      Format Code
//      Number of datapoints in series
//      Data values
//      Data Marker
$xAxisTickValues2 = array(
    new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Worksheet!$A$2:$A$5', NULL, 4),  //  Q1 to Q4
);
//  Set the Data values for each data series we want to plot
//      Datatype
//      Cell reference for data
//      Format Code
//      Number of datapoints in series
//      Data values
//      Data Marker
$dataSeriesValues2 = array(
    new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('Number', 'Worksheet!$C$2:$C$5', NULL, 4),
);

//  Build the dataseries
$series2 = new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries(
    PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::TYPE_DONUTCHART,     // plotType
    PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::GROUPING_STANDARD,   // plotGrouping
    range(0, count($dataSeriesValues2)-1),          // plotOrder
    $dataseriesLabels2,                             // plotLabel
    $xAxisTickValues2,                              // plotCategory
    $dataSeriesValues2                              // plotValues
);

//  Set up a layout object for the Pie chart
$layout2 = new PHPExcel_Chart_Layout();
$layout2->setShowVal(TRUE);
$layout2->setShowCatName(TRUE);

//  Set the series in the plot area
$plotarea2 = new PHPExcel_Chart_PlotArea($layout2, array($series2));

$title2 = new PHPExcel_Chart_Title('Test Donut Chart');


//  Create the chart
$chart2 = new PHPExcel_Chart(
    'chart2',       // name
    $title2,        // title
    NULL,           // legend
    $plotarea2,     // plotArea
    true,           // plotVisibleOnly
    0,              // displayBlanksAs
    NULL,           // xAxisLabel
    NULL            // yAxisLabel       - Like Pie charts, Donut charts don't have a Y-Axis
);

//  Set the position where the chart should appear in the worksheet
$chart2->setTopLeftPosition('I7');
$chart2->setBottomRightPosition('P20');

//  Add the chart to the worksheet
$objWorksheet->addChart($chart2);


// Save Excel 2007 file
echo date('H:i:s') , " Write to Excel2007 format" , EOL;
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->setIncludeCharts(TRUE);
$objWriter->save(str_replace('.php', '.xlsx', __FILE__));
echo date('H:i:s') , " File written to " , str_replace('.php', '.xlsx', pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_BASENAME)) , EOL;


// Echo memory peak usage
echo date('H:i:s') , " Peak memory usage: " , (memory_get_peak_usage(true) / 1024 / 1024) , " MB" , EOL;

// Echo done
echo date('H:i:s') , " Done writing file" , EOL;
echo 'File has been created in ' , getcwd() , EOL;
```

This is my PHPExcel pie example. It exports a excel file but it gives an error that the graph isn't properly rendered and it can be opened if Excel deletes the graph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but for newcomers.

This seems an [issue](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/pull/435) and it isn't fixed in the current version (1.8.1). Basically,

> You should not use PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::GROUPING_STANDARD for pie charts

Comment: Thank you. Although it's an old question, thanks for the answer, really appreciate it!